# Week to date or how do i account for the hours in today() or now()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I want to create a simple weekly stats script that enumerates activities of the week to date. So Monday morning to Sunday in our neck of the woods.
So far i have

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
for activity in client.get_activities(after=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=today.weekday())):
```

That works, but it doesn't account for the hours already passed today in now()
Monday should be always starting at 0:00, but i'm not sure how the best approach would be. Maybe substract the time from this morning up to now?

Expected would be that datetime.now() - timedelta(days=today.weekday()
returns stuff that happens between 0:00 and now is included in every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date.today()` to avoid getting the hours, minutes and seconds of the day:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
for activity in client.get_activities(after=today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())):
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes so much more sense.